# iPhone Download levels for application

Tags: iphone, ipad, scripting, download, lua

I am developing a 2d game for iPhone/iPad. Game will use lua for npc/location scripting and build-in lua interpreter.
I want to allow users to download new levels from our site. Level bundle will contain images, music and lua script that describe npc/location.

I know that Apple doesn't allow to download scripts from application. Maybe exist some workaround to do this? Script must have some limitations? Another script language? Lua byte-code?

Thank for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Apple changed the developer agreement a while back to allow for limited interpreted code to be downloaded to apps and run: http://touchreviews.net/apple-lua-iphone-developer-agreement/

I've heard from more than one person that there are many games already in the App Store that are using Lua in the capacity you're indicating with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch the scripts as a part of a large file then how would Apple know?  Also if your script is only used internally in your program then I can't see why that should be a problem.  One of my appstore programs uses an internal script interpreter and I've never received any comments or warnings from Apple.

You might run into problems if you start compiling the scripts or try to access the iOS API through scripts but I doubt that is something you are doing.